# Access Website With Reverse Proxy

Tags: web, proxy, webserver, reverse-proxy

I'm hoping to get some kind of idea if what I have in mind is even possible or if I'm looking in the wrong place.

Basically, my company provides a website which users are able to access online with credentials we sell and provide them. We have another potential customer who would like to access this website. Sadly this customer is very stuck in the past, and they don't allow their users any internet access at all.

For a number of reasons, I don't want them to host their own version of this website. However, I considered that we might configure a web proxy on their network (which is given internet access) which reverse forwards connections to our website. Is this even possible? And should it be attempted? Or are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can install on their intranet a simple proxy script for example

https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app

and modify the index.php and allow from there only a single host to your website.

I don't know what technology you can use on their Intranet network but virtually for every web language, such software is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some discussion related to the "Access the sites blocked over the network" that is just for Gmail but it will definitely help you too:

https://superuser.com/questions/453825/how-to-bypass-web-url-filtering-service-to-access-blocked-websites-proxy

For bypassing the firewall and getting access to the blocked sites:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-get-into-blocked-websites-in-school-with-freeproxy/

Comment: There is nothing that is impossible. There are a lot a of flaws in every network you just need to find the weakest link of the chain.

Comment: Just to clarify though... the customers' user don't have internet access. They have access to an intranet only. So it's not a case of bypassing a firewall, as there is no internet connection to use.